# Finite group acting on a curve and a line bundle with $G$ action

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve over $\mathbb{C}$ and $G$ be a finite group acting on $C$. Consider the quotient $f:C\rightarrow C'=C/G$. Suppose that $C'$ is smooth (I think this will be true, since the quotient by a finite group is normal, and hence non-singular for curves).

Consider a line bundle $L$ on $C$ with a $G$-action. It is possible that $L$ descends to $C'$, that is, there is a line bundle $L'$ in $C'$ such that $f^*L'=L$.

Suppose it doesn't consider the maximal subsheaf of $L$ which descends, say $L^G\subset L$. This has to either zero or a rank one sheaf.

1) Is $L^G$ locally free. Can it be a line bundle not equal to $L$. For example, this will be ruled out if $L/L^G$ is locally free.

2)We can similarly talk about $V^G$ for a vector bundle $G$. Will $V^G$ be a direct summand of $V$?

I would be grateful for some direction.

Comment: [This is possibly related](https://mathoverflow.net/q/109310).

Comment: @Jesko, thanks I just had a look at the thread. It talks about a connected algebraic group though. And it doesn't seem to address this question, directly at least.